# Как включить в Unity inspector?

Tags: unity3d

Эххх... Случайно закрыл, а найти не  могу. Погуглил, но так ответа и не нашел(.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понимаю, почему так много людей думают, что им легче задать *простейший* вопрос на сайте, ждать ответа на протяжении некоторого времени (**не** будучи уверенным, что ответ будет хороший), когда они могут сделать это: https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=1923018&text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%B2+unity&lr=9&redircnt=1628444605.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [Unity - Manual: The inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html) это окно можно открыть двумя способами:

1. Через главное меню: Windows > General > Inspector
2. Через кнопку "More items" у любого другого окна: Add Tab > Inspector

Answer (score 0):

интересно, как же это ты гуглил, самое первое видео по запросу:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wZGKhVyxRQ&ab_channel=%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80